# AWS Aurora Performance Insight Metric

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora

I notice there are Blk reads and Local blk reads in performance insights, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation from both AWS and PosgrestSQL explains the difference between them. Does anyone know what's the difference?

Comment: If anyone downvotes this, please let me know why

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in one part of the docs, but not in every place where the term (or similar) is used: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-explain.html

> local blocks contain data from temporary tables and indexes